# How to merge first index of an array with first index of other array

Tags: php, laravel

I want to combine two arrays, but I want to merge 1st index with 1st and 2nd with 2nd and so on.

```
$latlong = office::select('latitude', 'longitude')->get();
foreach ($latlong as $l)
{
    $lati = explode(',', $l->latitude);
    $longi = explode(',', $l->longitude);

    $result = array_merge($lati, $longi);
    dd($result);
}
```

Output:

```
array:8 [▼
    0 => "31.4824454"
    1 => "31.4824454"
    2 => "31.48306351"
    3 => ""
    4 => "74.3270004"
    5 => "74.31525707"
    6 => "74.31045055"
    7 => ""
]
```

Comment: what are your inputs?

Comment: have you tried with for loop?

Comment: im getting it from db

Comment: i'm not sur what is expected ?

Comment: 31.4824454,74.3270004
31.4824454,74.31525707
31.48306351,74.31045055

want this result

Comment: ok please edit your question with that and please add the input data

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to join values of two arrays like this

```
$latlong = office::select('latitude', 'longitude')->get();
foreach ($latlong as $l)
{
    $lati = explode(',', $l->latitude);
    $longi = explode(',', $l->longitude);

    $result = array_map(
        function($lat, $long) {
            return $lat . ", " . $long;
        },
        $lati,
        $longi
    )
    dd($result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should loop through the one array and fetch the results of both the array

```
$results = [];
    for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($lati);$i++){
        $result[] = [
            'lat' => $lati[$i],
            'lng' => $longi[$i],
        ]
    }
```

This will give you the array with lat long

Comment: `$lati` and `$longi` don't even exist.

Comment: You just need to interpret the logic, if you want to be copy cat I can help you out then

Comment: If your answer is blantantly wrong it shouldn't be there. There's no interpretation to have on an algorithm that should take 5 lines to do.

Comment: You think it is wrong. I don't think so. I have worked on same solution. Anyways it's up to you to accept it or not.

Comment: Just try your answer. It doesn’t work at all. You talk about 2 arrays while OP has only one.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
$coordinates = office::select('latitude', 'longitude')->get();

$result = [];
foreach ($coordinates as $c) {
    $result[] = $c->latitude . ', ' . $c->longitude;
}

dd($result);
```

Each row in $coordinates is an object that has both longitude and latitude, so you just have to loop over it and then store them in a new resulting array.